# Determine $|4 U_{5}(105)|$ in $U(105)/U_5(105)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$U(105)=\{1,11,1,26,31,41,46,61,71,76,86,101\}$ so $U_5(105)=\{x\in U(105) \mid x\equiv 1\pmod{5}\}=U(105)$ and $U(105)/U_5(105)=\{U(105)\}$.

I don't understand why would $4U_5(105)$ have an order in a group that it is not in.

I lifted this from Gallian, contemporary abstract algebra page 201.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$U(105)=U_5(105)$ is false. Note that $$U(105)=\{x : \gcd(x,105)=1\}\;\;\text{and}\;\;\vert U(105)\vert=\phi(105)=48$$

Also $$U_5(105)=\{x \in U(105): x \equiv1 (\text{mod} \;5)\}=\{1,11,16,26,31,41,46,61,71,76,86,101\}$$ so $G=U(105)/U_5(105)$ has order $48/12=4$

Now $4U_5(105)$ is an element of $G$ and you have to find a least $n$ so that $$\Big[4U_5(105)\Big]^n=U_5(105)$$

What is the least $n$ ?

> Ans: $n=2$